# SwiftUI calling searchable on a list combines all elements into one row

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the example below the list items get squished all into one cell of the list, but only when calling .searchable() on it. When I call .searchable() on the text everything displays normally. I can't use it on the text though, because it has problems with the search filter.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FoodItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ListView: View {
    
    let listContent: [FoodItem] = [FoodItem(name: "Food 1"), FoodItem(name: "Food 2")]

    @State public var searchQuery: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    List(filteredContent) { item in
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                    .searchable(text: $searchQuery)
                }
            } .navigationTitle("Food List")
        }
    }
    
    var filteredContent: [FoodItem] {
        if searchQuery.isEmpty {
            return listContent
        } else {
            return listContent.filter { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchQuery)}
        }
    }
}

struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListView()
    }
}
```

I spent probably two hours searching online and trying to fix it and didn't find any results. Also, I'm new to SwiftUI.

Thanks!!

Comment: Searchable needs to be on the text. The reason this doesn't work well is probably because you are creating your `listContent` inside the view and your food items will be getting new `id` values each time the view changes. You should inject your list into the view so that it remains consistent.

Comment: Section is usually inside List

Answer (score 0):

Paulw11's comment helped me a lot. I found out, that it wasn't the problem, that I called .searchable() on the text, but that I had an error in my `filteredContent`.

The problem was fixed with this:

```
var filteredContent: [FoodItem] {
    if searchQuery.isEmpty {
        return listContent
    } else if (listContent.filter {$0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchQuery)}.isEmpty) {
        return listContent
    } else {
        return listContent.filter { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchQuery)}
    }
}
```